# What is wrong with my smbclient

Tags: linux, smb, manjaro, smbclient

**Scenario**

Today I set up an smb share on my Linux desktop machine connected to my router via cable 1GBit/s. I tested the LAN speed between my Notebook(Manjaro, 5GHz) and desktop using iperf. Result is around 500Mbit/s in each direction.

**Transfer Speeds**

Transferring a large file from desktop to said Notebook results in a speed of around 3MB/s = 24Mbit/s. Using a windows machine to transfer the large file from linux desktop to windows machine results in a speed of around 160MBit/s. Now back at the Linux Notebook using sftp I get a speed of 160MBit/s.
File manager is dolphin for smb and sftp.

**Problem**

What is misconfigured on my Linux smbclient, that it can only reach a speed of 24 Mbit/s?

Comment: Make sure the server and client are both configured to use SMB v3.  Throughput can go way down with earlier versions of SMB, particularly on networks with latency.

Comment: @balazer that actually fixed my issue. No clue what version dolphin uses to mount my smb share, but atleast I mounted through console and everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As balazer stated in his comment, dolphin doesn't use v3 to mount the smb share. This was simply fixed using

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,vers=3.11 //ip/sharename /mnt`

Notice the vers=3.11